# En las configuraciones de paquetes de Kali Linux ¿ qué opción debo elegir para la configuración de sslh?

Tags: linux

acabo de descargar Kali Linux en una virtualbox y a la hora de ejecutar el comando sudo apt-get upgrade (que use para la actualización de los paquetes) me abrió un cuadro de dialogo con la leyenda "configuración de paquetes;  sslh configuración" y las opciones de  "ejecutar sslh:

1)desde inetd

2)de manera independiente ".

¿Qué opción es recomendable elegir? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sslh lo puedes ejecutar desde inetd o desde standalone, cada uno tiene sus ventajas, si tienes pocas conexiones es mejor que lo ejecutes desde el superservidor inetd para ahorrar recursos

Comment: ok, muchísimas gracias!!